# NodeJS Promise randomly returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

Firstly I'm sorry if this has already been answered, but I have searched for this kind of issue without finding anything useful.

I'm developing a NodeJS application that has to query a database with the mysql npm package. I have written several queries that have worked well with the help of promises (since it's what the SQL module works with), and the queries are good. When calling the query process function `get_works` (defined below) normally, I have no issue.
However, when I call this process function in the Express router a strange behavior occurs.

```js
view.get("/works", (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        res.json(await get_works());
    })()
});

async function get_works(offset=0,limit=6){

    let cdc_database = mysql.createConnection({
        /*Filled with credentials*/
    });
    
    const get_texts = `SELECT TEXID,TXNOM,TXRES FROM TEXTE LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset};`; // Valid request

    /*Two steps: get texts and get authors of each texts*/

    cdc_database.connect();
    const texts = await database_promise_query(cdc_database, get_texts);
    /*This await always have a correct output*/

    let text_authors = [];

    for(i = 0; i < texts.length; i++){

        get_text_authors = `SELECT AUPRE, AUNOM FROM AUTEURS,ECRIT_PAR\
        WHERE AUTEURS.AUTID=ECRIT_PAR.AUTID AND TEXID=${texts[i].TEXID};`; // Request is valid

        text_authors[i] = (await database_promise_query(cdc_database, get_text_authors));
        /*          ^^^^^^^^
        The await above returns an undefined value randomly when called through the router
        */
        if(text_authors[i] === undefined){
            console.error(`[get_works] - Server error on ${i}th text's authors`)
            text_authors[i] = [{AUPRE: "Prénom", AUNOM: "Nom"}]
        }

    }
    

    cdc_database.end();

    return works_to_JSON(texts, text_authors)
}
```

Sometimes, the queries to the database will have no undefined values, but once there is an undefined value, all the following are undefined too.

```
Example trace log

(1st call, 3 errors)
[
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: 'xxx' } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: "xxx" } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: 'xxx' } ],
  [ { AUPRE: 'Prénom', AUNOM: 'Nom' } ],
  [ { AUPRE: 'Prénom', AUNOM: 'Nom' } ],
  [ { AUPRE: 'Prénom', AUNOM: 'Nom' } ]
]

(2nd call, no error)
[
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: 'xxx' } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: "xxx" } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: 'xxx' } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: 'xxx' } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: "xxx" } ],
  [ RowDataPacket { AUPRE: 'xxx', AUNOM: 'xxx' } ],
]
```

Here is my promise wrapper:

```js
function database_promise_query(database, query){
    return new Promise(res => {
        database.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error) {res(undefined); console.log(error)}
            res(results);
        })
    })
}
```

However, calling this function outside of the router as is works like a charm:

```js
(async () => {
    await get_works(0, 10);
    await get_works(10, 10);
    await get_works(20, 10);
    await get_works(30, 10);
})()
```

Am I missing something ? I would assume that all the queries are correct since I can get the wanted result and the issue here would be my async/await managing. Thanks for all the help you could bring me.

## Edit 1

Following @tromgy's advice, I've rewritten the promise wrapper.

```js
function database_promise_query(database, query){
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        database.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error) {rej(error); throw new Error(error)}
            console.log("Received response", results)
            res(results);
        })
    })
}
```

However, the reject **never** occurs (which is logical because there is data that match in the database). In order to clean the logs, I disabled another router that makes a similar request, using a different database connection. Removing this router removed the bug too. I don't know how this is possible (maybe a variable is declared as global, so I'll look for this kind of issue).

Comment: It will be better to reject the promise on error instead of resolving to `undefined`.

Comment: Okay, thanks ! I've investigated and there is no error. The promise is always successful (because there is something in the database that matches). Apparently, another router that I use is somehow interfering with the works router.

I'll try to correct this and I'll post the answer, thank you again for your hint !

Answer (score 0):

As depicted in Edit 1, the issue was a shared loop counter. One of my colleagues forgot to add the `let` keyword before iterating, so the for loop was jumping values.

I now hate this javascript feature. Thanks for helping !